# logstash fitler how to get the designated fields form log data

Tags: filter, logstash

the log is like this:

```
{
"playerId": 2,
"args": {
    "uid": 2024657127,
    "__route__": "userCenter.playerHandler.getOnLineUids"
},
"time": "03122053",
"timeUsed": 8,
"resp": {
    "code": 200,
    "uidState": {
        "imId": 2024657127,
        "uid": 0,
        "state": 0
    }
}
```

}

I just need the "__route__" and "timeUsed",

```
filter {
if "__route__" in [message] {
    json {
        source => "message"
        remove_field => ["args.uid", "playerId", "time", "resp"]
    }
}}
```

the result in kibana like this:
[image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ418.png)

we can see the field "arg.uid" is also there,how to delete the field like it? Or any other better way to get "__route__" and "timeUsed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace args.uid with [args][uid] , it should work after that. Because in logstash every subfield is accessed by using [parent][child] notation

Comment: Atleast have the courtesy, to mark answer useful. If it worked for you.

Comment: I'm so sorry to that,yes i want to mark it but not found button to do that,i will try it again,thank a lot!

Comment: I appreciate your honesty. Thanks !!